# Missing parameter INPUT_A in qgis:rastercalculator

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I simply want to sum up two rasters with PyQGIS. To this end, I'm trying to use the `qgis:rastercalculator` but I encounter an error.

Here's the code:

```py
import processing

output_layer = '/tmp/result.tif'
params = {
    'LAYERS' : [ "Input_DEM@1", "Input_Overlay@1" ],
    'EXPRESSION': '+',
    'OUTPUT' : output_layer
}
processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator', params)
```

Which leads to this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 152, in runAndLoadResults
    context=context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 153, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT_A: no value specified for parameter
```

But I cannot figure out such an `INPUT_A` field in the doc: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastercalculator

Did I miss something? What should `INPUT_A` be?

Also, it's not 100% clear how to pass the input rasters from the documentation. I may also be wrong in my way of doing it.

**Info:**

QGIS version 3.16.3-Hannover
QGIS code revision 94ac9f21b8
OS Version Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason is because there's a difference between `gdal:rastercalculator` and `qgis:rastercalculator` in terms of the keyword arguments for the input.

The documentation you referred to is for the QGIS version of this tool (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastercalculator), whilst in your code you're calling the `gdal` raster calculator, which indeed accepts the first keyword argument as `INPUT A`.

Here is the revised code that worked for me:

```
import processing

output_layer = '/tmp/result.tif'
params = {
    'LAYERS' : ['/tmp/input1.tif'],
    'EXPRESSION': '\"input1@1\" + \"input1@1\"',
    'OUTPUT' : output_layer
}
processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:rastercalculator', params)
```

You can use this code to view the help (and arguments) for each one of the algorithms, here is the code for the GDAL raster calculator:

```
processing.algorithmHelp("gdal:rastercalculator")
```

Comment: Ouch, Doh! Thanks for being my eyes. I've noticed that all tools in my raster menu are indeed GDAL tools and not QGIS by looking closer to the icon :/ !! Also, do you mind fixing your output_layer variable? You defined it but didn't actually use it (but maybe it was meant to be used for the OUTPUT param?

Comment: No worries, it is indeed quite confusing as they carry otherwise an identical name! And sure, thanks for the correction I adjusted the code sample.